# Extract value from an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

In my code, $return returns an array of data. I am trying to extract the [2] value in that array. For some reason it just returns the whole array instead of the value I am trying to extract. I feel like this is really simple and I am just overlooking something.

Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://sandbox.familysearch.org/platform/tree/persons/KWWM-5R1/portrait?access_token=' . $_SESSION['fs-session'];

$return = print_r(get_headers($url));

echo $return[2];
```

And here is a snip from the array that was printed:

```
Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect [1] => Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 [2] => Location: https://integration.familysearch.org/sandbox/v2/TH-501-48051-27-34/thumb200.jpg?ctx=ArtCtxPublic )
```

How can I get the [2] value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting rid of the `print_r`:

```
$return = get_headers($url);
echo $return[2];
```

`print_r` is a function used to print out information from a variable (in the case of your array, its contents). You're setting `$return` equal to the return value of `print_r` (which is just `true`), rather than the headers array you want.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$url = 'https://sandbox.familysearch.org/platform/tree/persons/KWWM-5R1/portrait?access_token=' . $_SESSION['fs-session'];

$return = get_headers($url);

echo $return[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

`$return = print_r(get_headers($url));`

should be `$return =get_headers($url);`

What you are seeing on screen is the result of the `print_r()`. This does not return an array to be assigned to `$return` instead it is just printing it in the screen.

So technically your `$return` does not have any value and your echo statement is actually not echoing anything.